# how to automatic create a folder in unix acording to the monthly file

Tags: unix, filenames

I have a file named as TEST123_20112020.csv

I have a constant path as processed/daily/ where the file will be transferred daily.

I need to know the Unix command which will create the directory according to the year and month of the file respectively and will transfer that file as well to that directory.

For eg:

File Name : TEST123_20112020.csv
Directory : processed/daily/2020/Nov

File Name : TEST123_15092022.csv
Directory : processed/daily/2020/Sep

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with find piped through to awk and so:

```
find . -name "TEST123.*csv" | awk -F[_\.] '{ yr=substr($2,length($2)-3);yr1=substr($2,length($2)-1);dat1=substr($2,1,4)""yr1;"date -d \""dat1"\" +%b" | getline mon;print "mkdir processed/daily/"yr"/"mon }'
```

Take the output of the find command, set the field delimiter to _ and . in awk with -F Then set the variable yr to the full year using awk's substr function. Set the two digit year (yr1) to be used with the date command later. Set a date command compliant date (dat1) utilising yr1 and then use this with a date command and awk's get line to read this into a variable mon. The variable mon with contain the  short form month name as required. Finally print this month along with the year to form a mkdir command.

Once you have verified that this command is as expected (this is important!) you can substitute the final print command for awk's system function to actually execute the command and so:

```
find . -name "TEST123.*csv" | awk -F[_\.] '{ yr=substr($2,length($2)-3);yr1=substr($2,length($2)-1);dat1=substr($2,1,4)""yr1;"date -d \""dat1"\" +%b" | getline mon;system("mkdir processed/daily/"yr"/"mon) }'
```